# Python code after sockets connection executed only once

Tags: sockets, python-3.x, pyserial

What are the intentions of this program:

I want to send some commands from a client to a server using sockets, the server then send these command to an Arduino using serial. And another thing that I want the server to do in the future is that periodically sends other commands to the Arduino without getting any input from the client, so the sockets needs to be non-blocking or there needs to be another way to run the code separately from the sockets code.

The problem is that the part that is supposed to send the command to the Arduino only runs once.

What I have come up with after playing with the debugger in Pycharm, is that the  problem is that the following line blocks after a connection has been established, and thus not allowing the rest of the code to be run.

```
conn, addr = s.accept()
```

Is this correct, or is there something else wrong?

I have tried to set the socket to non-blocking but when I do this I get an error.

```
"BlockingIOError: [WinError 10035] A non-blocking socket operation could not be completed immediately"
```

I have some basic knowledge of C/C++ and C# and am new to Python.

**server.py**

```
import socket
import serial
import sys
from _thread import *
import threading
import queue

# command that the client sends are "ON" and "OFF"

class serialConnect:
    comPort =' '
    baudrate = 115200
    myserial = serial.Serial('COM5', baudrate)
    def serialstart(self):
       # self.comPort = input('Comport: ')
        try:
            self.myserial.open()
        except IOError:
            print('Port is already open!')

    def serialRead(self):
        data = self.myserial.read(16)
        data.decode('UTF-8')
        return data

    def serialWrite(self, data):
        data += '\n'        #the arduino needs a \n after each command.
        databytes = data.encode('UTF-8')
        self.myserial.write(databytes)
        print('send data: ', databytes)


def threaded_client(conn, dataqueue):
    data = {bytes}
    conn.send(str.encode('welcome, type your info \n'))
    while True:
        data = conn.recv(2048)
        if not data:
            break
        reply = 'server output: ' + data.decode('UTF-8')
        dataqueue.put(data.decode('UTF-8'))
        print("Items in queue: ",dataqueue.qsize())
        #conn.sendall(str.encode(reply))
        print("Recieved data in threaded_client: ", data.decode('UTF-8') + '\n')

    conn.close()

def Main():

    ser = serialConnect()
    host = ''
    port = 5555
    dataRecieved = 'hello'
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.settimeout(2)
    s.setblocking(1)   #when set to non-blocking error occurs : "BlockingIOError: [WinError 10035] A non-blocking socket operation could not be completed immediately"
    workQueue = queue.Queue(10)

    try:
        s.bind((host,port))
    except socket.error as e:
        print(str(e))

    s.listen(5)
    print('waiting for a connection')

    while True:
        try:
            conn, addr = s.accept() #once connection is established it blocks?
            print('connected to: ' + addr[0] + ':' + str())
            t = threading.Thread(target=threaded_client, args=(conn, workQueue))
            t.daemon = True
            t.start()

        except:
            e = sys.exc_info()
            print('Error:', e)

        # This section of code is only run once, doesn't matter if put inside try block or not. :(
        dataRecieved = workQueue.get()
        print('The recieved data: ', dataRecieved)
        ser.serialstart()
        ser.serialWrite(dataRecieved)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Main()
```

**client.py**

```
import socket



def Main():
    host = '127.0.0.1'
    port = 5555

    message = "<,R,G,B,>"
    mySocket = socket.socket()
    mySocket.connect((host, port))

    while message != 'q':
        message = input(" -> ")
        mySocket.send(message.encode())
    mySocket.close()




if __name__ == '__main__':
    Main()
```

**Arduino Code**

```
String inputString = "";         // a string to hold incoming data
boolean stringComplete = false;  // whether the string is complete

int LEDpin = 10;
// the setup function runs once when you press reset or power the board
void setup() {
  // initialize digital pin 13 as an output.
  pinMode(10, OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin(19200);
}

// the loop function runs over and over again forever
void loop() {
  serialEvent();
  if(stringComplete){
    Serial.println(inputString);
    if(inputString == "ON\n"){
      digitalWrite(LEDpin, HIGH);   // turn the LED on (HIGH is the voltage level)
      }
     if(inputString == "OFF\n"){
       digitalWrite(LEDpin, LOW);    // turn the LED off by making the voltage LOW
      }
    inputString = "";
    stringComplete = false;
    }
}
void serialEvent()
{
  while (Serial.available()) {
    // get the new byte:
    char inChar = (char)Serial.read();
    // add it to the inputString:
    inputString += inChar;
    // if the incoming character is a newline, set a flag
    // so the main loop can do something about it:
    if (inChar == '\n') {
      stringComplete = true;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Your naming convention is C#-Style. Python uses names_like_this for anything except classes. Besides, you should use `with` statement instead of the explicit `.close()`

Comment: `accept` *should* block until you get a connection. Once you accept a first connection, your code spawns a separate thread that handles that connection, but then the main thread will run through the rest of its loop (once) and then execute `accept` again. And so it will block until you get *another* connection. If that's not what you want to happen, you need to restructure your code.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I have refactored the code and now it's working the way I want it(for now at least).
See the edit for the new server code, al the other code has stayed the same.

Comment: Try write `sys.exc_info()` to `SQL`.  Don't print console all exceptions ! Print always work on `when building a app`, you already got `SQL` connection(use for solution).

Answer (score 2):

**Refactored server code for anyone that is interested in it.**

I am not sure if this is up to standard, but it is working.

```
import serial
import socket
import queue
import sys
import threading

class serialConnect:
    comPort = 'COM5'
    baudrate = 115200
    myserial = serial.Serial(comPort, baudrate)

    def serial_run(self):
       # self.comPort = input('Comport: ')
        try:
            if not self.myserial.isOpen():
                self.myserial.open()
            else:
                print('Port is already open!')
        except IOError as e:
            print('Error: ', e)

    def serial_read(self):
        data = self.myserial.read(16)
        data.decode('UTF-8')
        return data

    def serial_write(self, data):
        data += '\n'        #the arduino needs a \n after each command.
        databytes = data.encode('UTF-8')
        self.myserial.write(databytes)
        print('send data: ', databytes)


class socketServer:
    host = ''
    port = 5555
    soc = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    soc.setblocking(1)
    data_queue = queue.Queue(1)

    def __init__(self):
        try:
            self.soc.bind((self.host, self.port))
        except:
            print('Bind error: ', sys.exc_info())
        self.soc.listen(5)

    def socket_accept_thread(self):
        while True:
            try:
                print('Waiting for a new connection')
                conn, addr = self.soc.accept()
                client_thread = threading.Thread(target=self.threaded_client, args=(conn, self.data_queue))
                client_thread.daemon = True
                client_thread.start()
            except:
                print('Accept thread Error: ', sys.exc_info())

    def threaded_client(self, conn, data_queue):
        # conn.send(str.encode('welcome, type your info \n'))
        try:
            while True:
                data = conn.recv(2048)
                if not data:
                    break
                # reply = 'server output: ' + data.decode('UTF-8')
                data_queue.put(data.decode('UTF-8'))
                print("Items in queue: ", data_queue.qsize())
                # conn.sendall(str.encode(reply))
                print("Received data in threaded_client: ", data.decode('UTF-8'))
        except:
            print("Error: ", sys.exc_info())
        conn.close()

    def get_data(self):
        data = self.data_queue.get()
        return data


def Main():
    server = socketServer()
    arduino_conn = serialConnect()
    accept_thread = threading.Thread(target=server.socket_accept_thread)

    data_received = 'Nothing received'

    while True:
        if not accept_thread.is_alive():
            accept_thread.daemon = True
            accept_thread.start()

        arduino_conn.serial_run()
        data_received = server.get_data()
        arduino_conn.serial_write(data_received)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Main()
```